# slow invariant inference with Horn clauses in Z3

Tags: z3

I've played with the following example in Z3/Horn (`unstable` branch)

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun inv (Int) Bool)
(assert (inv 0))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (and (<= I 1000) (inv I)) (inv (+ I 1)))))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (inv I) (<= I 10000))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

It takes 8.5s to infer the invariant x≤1001. This is unexpectedly long...

Time increases to 19 seconds if I replace 1000 by 1500 and to 34 seconds if I replace 1000 by 2000. This seems to indicate quadratic behaviour with respect to the loop bound.

I find it curious that it takes so much time to verify an assertion that is clearly inductive...

Comment: Nice example, but what is the question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong that makes it so slow? Am I using it in an unintended way?

Comment: You do nothing wrong. It is a good example to show where performance of the abstraction-refinement loop is slow.
Auxiliary invariants could for instance do much better.

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop on this question.
First of all, it is a very good example to illustrate some points.

The PDR engine in Z3 uses a monolithic strategy for generating 
intermediary assertions. Intuitively, it is based on under-approximating 
strongest post-conditions. It does not attempt to search within the spectrum
of interpolant strengths.
The example converges much faster (instantly)
if applying a magic set transformation (e.g, inverting the transition system):

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun inv (Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (not (<= I 10000)) (inv I))))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (and (<= I 1000) (inv (+ I 1))) (inv I))))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (inv I) (not (= I 0)))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```